# Trying to split array of objects based on a common key of the objects with swift

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift

I'm completely lost with swift. I am trying to split an array of objects (retrieved using the Parse SDK) based on a common key.
Basically I would like to make a COUNT + GROUP BY, but I could not find a way to make a GROUP BY with the Parse SDK, so I am trying to group the objects and count them by the code.
But first, what I am writing looks horrible, and secondly that does not even compile and I can't understand why.

This is the code I'm using

```
var groupedEntries = [String: [String: AnyObject?]]()

...

let query = PFQuery(className: "Entry")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
   if error == nil {

      var groupingKey: String
      for object in objects {

         groupingKey = object[groupingKey] as String
         if self.groupedEntries[groupingKey] != nil {
            self.groupedEntries[groupingKey]["count"] = self.groupedEntries[groupingKey]["count"] + 1
         } else {
            self.groupedEntries[groupingKey]["count"] = 1
         }
      }
      self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

And the compiler gives the following error : 'String' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex'. Whatever I try I get an error related to optionals or wrapping.

Thanks to anybody that will help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `subscript` the `Dictionary` returns optional of given value type so you need to unwrap it.You need to take the extra variable i used `somevar`.See below code

```
var groupedEntries = [String: [String: AnyObject?]]()

@IBAction func changeImage(sender: AnyObject){
    var objects:[AnyObject]!
    var groupingKey: String //= "abc" Intialize before using
    //var countryCode: String   //= "abc" not defined in your code

    for object in objects {

        groupingKey = object[groupingKey] as String
        if self.groupedEntries[groupingKey] != nil {
            var somevar = self.groupedEntries[groupingKey]!
            somevar["count"] = (somevar["count"]! as Int) + 1
        } else {
            self.groupedEntries[groupingKey] = ["count":1]
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know about your logic but this code compiles well.

Comment: Well, this compile, but generates an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION exception on the "else" statement (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value).

Comment: you should check `self.groupedEntries[countryCode]` for nil also if nil need to intialize it

Comment: It is improvement but these kind of stuff really get mess if you do not use good techniques.Study good Json parsing library code

Comment: Sorry used `countryCode` instead of `groupingKey`.Not saw your edit. edited answer

Comment: @codester, in the else clause, `self.groupedEntries[groupingKey]` is `nil` as established by the `if`.  I suggest first setting it to a new dictionary.

Comment: `self.groupedEntries[groupingKey] = ["count":1]` should do it.

Comment: Thanks, codester you should add the vacawama code into the else, so I can validate your answer.